# jquery div width Height re-position (dynamic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am accustomed to FIXED Height/Width aspect ratio, but now I'm attempting dynamic Height/Width ratio.  I for the life outta me cannot think how to implement this with the dynamic.

For instance, at H:800,W:800 (Fixed Map), the dots (emulates as coord) @ 0,0 - 0,800 - 400,400 - 800,0 - 800,800, I know exactly where the dot goes with CSS(TOP LEFT)

With this map is 800x1000: I need to think HOW i can MAKE the dot go at: 0,0 - 0,1000 - 400,500 - 1000,0 - 1000,1000

or say map is 900x900: dot goes at: 0,0 - 0,900 - 450,450 - 900,0 - 900,900, so on, I think we get the idea.

This is what i used to calculate the size of the DIV to prepare myself for Dynamic:

```
var AH = $('#MapBox').outerHeight(true);
var AW = $('#MapBox').outerWidth(true);
```

for fixed dot, I used but cannot figure out dynamic:

```
tX = parseFloat(item.FieldID % 800);
tY = parseInt(item.FieldID / 800);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your goal. Depending on the source of your coordinates, you can fix this in javascript or css. (And I see your using MapBox, perhaps the thing you want to do is also available within that library, but that is out of scope for this question).

### Javascript

Lets say your source is a list of coordinates:

```
var coords = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 800],
  [400, 400],
  [800, 0]
  [800, 800]
]
```

These coordinates are based on a field of size `800x800`. Lets call this the `baseSize`.

```
baseSizeX = 800;
baseSizeY = 800;
```

Also define a target size:

```
targetSizeX = 800; // or $('#MapBox').outerWidth(true);
targetSizeY = 1000; // or $('#MapBox').outerHeight(true);
```

Now you need to calculate a scale factor that you can apply to your coordinates. This is simply the ratio: `base / target`.

```
scaleX = targetSizeX / baseSizeY; // 800 / 800 = 1
scaleY = targetSizeY / baseSizeY; // 1000 / 800 = 1.25
```

To finish up, just scale each coordinate:

```
const X = 0;
const Y = 1;

for( coord of coords ){
  coord[X] = coord[X] * scaleX;
  coord[Y] = coord[Y] * scaleY;
}
```

### CSS

In case your coordinates are static (eg. you want a dot in the left top, center bottom, right bottom etc) you can also just use CSS, no scripts needed. You can think of the coordinates as percentages; given a container of `800x800`

- `(0, 0)` equals `top: 0%; left: 0%`
- `(800, 0)` equals `top: 100%; left: 0%`
- `(400, 400)` equals `top: 50%; left 50%`

You could define the following CSS:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}

.container .first-dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}

.container .second-dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

/* Etc. */
```

Comment: It gave me a broad general idea where to start, that helps alot.. Now to see how I'd implement them :)  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: To finish up, just scale each coordinate:

const X = 0;
const Y = 1;

for( coord of coords ){
  coord[X] = coord[X] * scaleX;
  coord[Y] = coord[Y] * scaleY;
}

trying to figure where you get the number for x/y in const?

Comment: Nvm, I got it figured out, its negliable.. again many thanks!